# Accessing global variables in JavaScript functions

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-3, view, global-variables

I am using C# asp.net mvc3.
In one of my views, say I declare a variable like this:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "title"   
    string mystr;  
}
```

I need to set the value of the variable mystr in a function of the script. How do I access this variable from the script? 
Suppose I have a function like

```
<Script type="text/javascript">
function(){
    var st = "This string is for the global variable"
     mystr = st;
}
</script>
```

mystr will later be used in the html code like this:
`<h2>@mystr</h2>` . 
Is there a similar way of accessing a variable from a function?

Comment: Your asp.net code is executed first on the server then later on the client then the JavaScript is executed, so by the time your js is executing all you asp.net code will have already run.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but aren't `@` variables used for data binding? That would happen server-side, while javascript is client-side.

Comment: You may want to read up on how the client/server relationship works in regard to web pages. .NET tries to muddy this division and ends up confusing many developers.

Comment: Thanks. How can i then update the value of a variable like "mystr" above in the js function? I mean, how do i access this variable from the function?

Answer (score 0):

`mystr` in your example is **server side** variable that lives during `cshtml` view parsing. So you can't affect it with JS code on the **client side**. You can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.mystr = @(mystr); // Set value while server side processing.
function(){
    var st = "This string is for the global variable"
    window.mystr = st; // Get/Set value
}
</script>
```

And use global variable `mystr` on client side wherever you need.

If you need then set header's text via JS you can do it for example with jQuery:

```
<h2 id="header"></h2>
```

JS:

```
$('#header').text(window.mystr);
```

Comment: Is it possible to set like this `window.mystr = @(mystr);`? I guess something like `var subpanelData= '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewData["Data"]))'` would be helpful on setting value from server side..